# Identifying fragments of First Order Logic, where the number of models increases strictly monotonically with the domain size?

Tags: combinatorics, first-order-logic

Given a function-free first order logic language with only universal quantification. The problem of model counting aims at finding the number of models that an FOL formula of the form $\forall {\bf{x}}. \Phi(\bf{x})$ has over a fixed domain of size $n$ (for more details see this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.1505.pdf)). Notice that $\bf{x}$ denotes $k$ distinct variables i.e. ${\bf{x}} = (x_1,...,x_k) $.We denote the number of models of $\forall {\bf{x}}. \Phi(\bf{x})$ over a domain of size $n$ as $FOMC(\forall {\bf{x}}. \Phi({\bf{x}}), n)$.

My question is that, is there a simple way (polynomial in $n$) to check if a formula's model count is strictly monotonically increasing in the following sense:

$$\forall n. FOMC(\forall {\bf{x}}. \Phi({\bf{x}}), n) \geq n^{k} \times FOMC(\forall {\bf{x}}. \Phi({\bf{x}}), k)$$

It would be fine if we can replace $n^{k}$ with any other reasonable function of $n$.

Comment: Do you mean "polynomial in the size of $\Phi$"? $n$ is not a parameter of your problem.

Comment: @RobArthan in principle you could just do the model count for each $n$ and check wether the provided condition is satisfied or not, but this is exponential in $n$. That's why I think $n$ is a parameter (but yes I am a bit confused now, as I require for all $n$). But to answer your comment, I am allowed to be exponential in size of $\Phi$